# Which Schema.org LocalBusiness type should I use for Business Centers, Coworking spaces and Serviced Offices?

Tags: schema.org

I'm looking to implement Schema.org on a website that lists Business Centers, Coworking Spaces in Italy.

Since I'm relatively new to all this structured data thing, I'm not sure if I just have to go with the generic [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness) or if there is a more specific type I can use.

I see that there are [`LodgingBusiness`](http://schema.org/LodgingBusiness), [`InternetCafe`](http://schema.org/InternetCafe) and [`SelfStorage`](http://schema.org/SelfStorage), but none of this fits.

Also, since they "sell", "offer", "rent" office spaces and other serices, I'm not sure if I should use the [`Product`](http://schema.org/Product) data too.

Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The website that list these is the business? Or is the website just one business, and each coworking space is owned by other businesses?

Comment: Tthe website is a directory of indipendent Business Centers, each one of them is an indipendent business. I'm not sure that linking the site is allowed, anyway here it is: http://ufficiarredati.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap your business into a service, then give it a use ServiceType since you're free to write what you want in there.
Here an example in JSON

> ```
> {
> "@context": "http://schema.org/",
> "@type": "Service",
> "serviceType": "Shared Office Space",
> "provider": {
> "@type": "LocalBusiness",
> "name": "My Business center"
> },
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look at what you have. According to schema.org:

- A `LodgingBusiness` is defined as "A lodging business, such as a motel, hotel, or inn." Since your business center/coworking space isn't renting sleeping arrangements, this isn't right.
- An `InternetCafe` isn't right, not based on the data provided by the schema classification, but by the fact that you're not providing short-term internet access for small numbers of clients at a time.
- `SelfStorage` isn't right because you actually have clients occupying the building during their workday (or overnight, for those crazy game developers or night-shifters). Self-storage facilities are for rental of storage space, and generally these aren't occupied by people ([unless you have no choice](http://www.johnnywander.com/)).
- Even `EmploymentAgency` doesn't quite fit what you need, though I have to say it's pretty close.

None of these are good fits for what you're trying to do; I think the best choice is just to stick with `LocalBusiness`.